# Why are wildcards only meant to work on individual search terms, not on phrase searches?

Tags: solr, lucene

Don't understand why the first search works while the second does not?

1. `softwar* eng?neering`
2. `"softwar* eng?neering"`

And if you need the ability to perform wildcard searches within a phrase, you will have to store the entire phrase in the index as a single term.

According to Solr in Action, 2014, wildcards are only
meant to work on individual search terms, not on phrase searches.

What's the reason behind that prevents the second from working in Solr? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work by default is that the analysis chain isn't invoked fully for wild card searches, since you can't really know to process or where to split the different terms into tokens when a wildcard is active. Those filters that *can* be applied are those that are MultiTermAware.

To make it work for phrase searches as wildcards, you'd effectively have a to match against the whole field value. I.e. `"softwar* eng?neering" should match`software foobar cheese engeneering`, which is far beyond what the initial phrase query would have to match.

You can however perform these matches as long as you have the text as a single token instead of as separate token, or by using a different query parser as suggested by Persimmonium.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you use the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser)